# Monotouch App Crashes when a tableView is removed from it's superview

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, tableview

I have a tableview where each cell contains a textview. 
Steps to reproduce the crash.

---

1. Write something in the textview of first row (keyboard is open)
2. Scroll the tableview downwards where the first row is not visible anymore . however, the keyboard is still open
3. I choose another tab where in code I remove the view which contains the tableview from its superview then the app crashes

Here is the stack trace

```
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00024, 0xffffffff>
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView.RemoveFromSuperview () [0x00031] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIView.g.cs:848`
```

---

i tried to perform a ResignFirstResponder with the same results.
Moreover, if the keyboard is not opened there is no crash

---

It is only reproduced on **IOS 7**

Comment: It looks like this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13430

Comment: I don’t see the relevance because I don’t override RemoveFromSuperview

Comment: Then I suggest you provide a complete sample I can look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the **UITableViewCells** i am creating in my UITableViewSource are being freed by the managed garbage collector, because they're not referenced from managed code when that method exits.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

- Keep a list of cells you've created in a class variable in the UITableViewSource class. The problem with this approach is that you have extra bookkeeping to do in order to remove cells from the list when they're no longer used.
- Create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell. Custom subclasses are treated differently at runtime in Xamarin.iOS, and we make sure they're not freed until their corresponding native object is freed:

---

```
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
   public CustomCell(UITableViewCellStyle Style, string Identifier) : base(Style, Identifier) { }
}
```